# Django Loop returning one row

Tags: django

I have encountered this challenge but i can really seem to get any step.

I want to populate all objects(Student) with all related Results,but i can only get the last related row after looping.

merits list page:

[image: 1]

its it returning details of Junior githambo for all objects.

**Models**

```
class Result(models.Model):     
    grade=models.TextField(max_length=5)
    marks=models.DecimalField(max_digits=5,decimal_places=2)    
    subject=models.ForeignKey(
        to='Subject',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
        )   
    student=models.ForeignKey(
        to='Student',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
        )

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {} {}'.format(self.student,self.subject,self.marks)

class Student(models.Model):    
    f_name=models.TextField(max_length=100)
    s_name=models.TextField(max_length=100)
    surname=models.TextField(max_length=100)
    reg_number=models.TextField(max_length=100) 
    photo=models.ImageField(upload_to='student_image')  
    next_of_kin=models.ForeignKey(
        to='Parent',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
        )
    student_form=models.ForeignKey(
        to='Class',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE

        )

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('student:student-detail',kwargs={'pk':self.id})

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {} {}'.format(self.s_name,self.surname,self.f_name)
```

**Views**

```
def student_merit_list(request):
    template_name='student/merit.html'
    all_student=Student.objects.all()
    for s in all_student:                   
        results=Result.objects.filter(student=s.id)
        total=results.aggregate(Sum('marks'))['marks__sum']
        mean_score=total/results.aggregate(Count('marks'))['marks__count']
        mean_grade=get_mean_grade(mean_score)       
        context={'s':s,'all_student':all_student,'results':results,'total':total,'mean_score':mean_score,'mean_grade':mean_grade}
    return render(request,template_name,context)
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly. Right now it does not make sense.

Comment: You are overwriting the context with every single iteration of all_students. Try to insert the results into a list or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Snackoverflow, you are overwriting the context with every student iteration. Therefore, first define your context before the for loop, like this:

```
def student_merit_list(request):
    template_name='student/merit.html'
    all_student=Student.objects.all()
    s = []
    results = []
    total = []
    mean_score = []
    mean_grade = []
    context = {'s':s,'all_student':all_student,'results':results,'total':total,'mean_score':mean_score,'mean_grade':mean_grade}
    for s in all_student:                   
        results=Result.objects.filter(student=s.id)
        total=results.aggregate(Sum('marks'))['marks__sum']
        mean_score=total/results.aggregate(Count('marks'))['marks__count']
        mean_grade=get_mean_grade(mean_score)
        s.append(s)
        all_student.append(all_student)
        results.append(results)
        # etc.       
        
    return render(request,template_name,context)
```